# py2exe skipping some py files

Tags: python, py2exe

So,

I have a legacy python system that has some oddities to it that py2exe (0.6.9) is having trouble with.

Specifically, a number of the py files in the project are included in a non-standard way, to the automatic detection of which files to compile and include misses them, resulting in an executable that fails to run.

In the past we have used a 'ForcedImport.py' file with all the known files manually included in it, and then that file referenced by anything that will be used to build an executable but this has always been a pretty clunky and fragile way to get them into the final build.

So my question is, is there a nice correct way to do this?  Some way to tell py2exec 'yes, I want you to include these py files in the build'?  I have tried to look through the documentation but, as much as I hate to admit it, I am not following a lot of it.

Thanks for any advice that can be passed back along.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of your modules in a package you can simply add that package in your setup.py

```
options = {
    "py2exe":{
                    "packages": ["yourpackage"],
            }
}
```